# Understanding appliction of sum notation with fraction - beginner question

Tags: notation, fractions

Given :

$$
Q_n=\frac{R_1+R_2+...+R_{n-1}}{n-1}
$$

$$
R = {1,2}
$$

Is my calculation of $Q_n$ values correct ? :

$$
Q_1=\frac{1 + R_0}{0}=\frac{1 + 0}{1-0} ?
$$

$$
Q_2=\frac{R_1+R_2+R_{2-1}}{2-1} =\frac{1+2+1}{2-1} ?
$$

$$
R = {1,2,3,4,5}
$$
therefore :

$$
Q_4=\frac{1+2+3}{3-1} ?
$$

Comment: where you want $Q_1$ then you should define $R_0$ as well, but you mentioned $R=1,2$ what does exactly that mean?

Comment: @user715522 that won't help because you will have to divide the RHS by zero

Comment: so the fraction is not well-defined for $n=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. Note that in this notation, $Q_1$ is not defined and then
$$
\begin{split}
Q_2 &= \frac{R_1}{2-1} = R_1\\
Q_3 &= \frac{R_1 + R_2}{3-1} = \frac{R_1 + R_2}{2}\\
Q_4 &= \frac{R_1 + R_2 + R_3}{4-1} = \frac{R_1 + R_2 + R_3}{3}\\
\ldots
\end{split}
$$

The intent, although somewhat obscure, was to define
$$
Q_n = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} R_k,
$$
in other words, the series $(Q_n)$ is really an average of $(R_n)$.

---

If you want to have a similar series with $Q_1$ defined, you can consider an alternative definition
$$
Q_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n R_k.
$$